# How to get the same timestamp from pandas dataframe to json file

Tags: python, pandas

### Summary

Need to retain the same timestamp format from pandas dataframe while converting into newline delimited json in python.

```
Input in dataframe: 2020-08-17 07:38:02
Expected after converting into json: 2020-08-17 07:38:02
```

### My try 1

```
df.to_json("C:/myfolder/myfile.json",
           orient="records", date_format='iso', date_unit='s',
           lines=True)
```

> Actual result with try 1 : 2020-08-17T07:38:02Z

### My try 2

```
df.to_json("C:/myfolder/myfile.json",
           orient="records",
           lines=True)
```

> Actual result with try 2 : 1597649882000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your type `dataframe` date column is `datetime` that's why when u convert it into `json` it get stocked like this format instead you can convert your column type like this.

```
df["date"]=df["date"].astype(str)
df.to_json("path",orient="records",lines=True)
```